# Nginx rewrite and 50x.html

Tags: nginx, php, web-server, rewrite

I'm trying to set up a website where writing for example

```
/users/add
```

redirects me to

```
/index.php?table=users&action=add
```

I wrote the following rules:

```
rewrite ^/(.+)/(.+)/$ /index.php?table=$1&action=$2 break;
rewrite ^/(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?table=$1&action=$2 break;
rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /index.php?table=$1&action=$2 break;
rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?table=$1&action=$2 break;
```

I did this because if I write just /users/, for example, the rule doesn't apply. In addition, I had to write two rules for each case because if I have e.g. "/users/add/", I get "add/" (with the slash) as the second parameter.

This doesn't really work because if I for example want to access "50x.html", I get the string as the parameter "table". How can I rewrite the rules (maybe combine them) so I can access the files AND use the friendly URLs? Thanks!

Comment: `try_files` should be used to allow accessing existing files and only falling back to PHP if one isn't found.

Comment: URL parsing should be in your application, not in your rewrite rules.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with Michael Hampton.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with Michael.

But you have to have choice.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @php;
}

location @php {
    # suppose you don't mind if in url /users/add/blabla, blabla will be lost
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)(/([^/]+)?)? /index.php?table=$1&action=$3 break;
    fastcgi_pass ...;
    # other params
}
```